# Can browser emulation create vulnerabilities?

Tags: risk-management, threat-mitigation, risk-analysis, vulnerability-management

If a browser is not authorized on a network, can browser emulation within an authorized browser create vulnerabilities?

For instance, Chrome is unauthorized but if I run IE, press F12 to get into Developer mode, and then have it emulate Chrome, will it just change how it deals with HTTP traffic, how it makes the page appear, or will it take on the security profile of Chrome?

To make the question more targeted and clear: say that Chrome has vulnerabilities A, B, and C. Will emulation inherit those same vulnerabilities? It's nothing specific but how much is being emulated, exactly?

Beyond that, threat assessments that kept Chrome from being authorized can be weighed to see if those still exist on a case-by-case basis. So, I'm just wanting to see what is changed in the broad scope.

Answer (score 1):

The emulation features within a browser emulate they way in which the DOM is interpreted (in a nutshell how the page should be displayed and respond).

Vulnerabilities within a browser do not carry across to the emulation (unless the vulnerability exists within the host browser as well).

Therefore in your example, if the emulator itself has a bug, even if you are emulating Chrome, the vulnerability is within IE.

Comment: Could certain aspects of the DOM be suppressed in one browser but allowed during emulation as another browser? Scripts perform DOM injections, so, could that alteration bring about vulnerabilities? A script section could check for a browser type and execute code depending on that browser (standard front-end behavior).